# How to block downloads from app store?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, webserver

I want to block the iPhone users connected to my home network from downloading apps from the apple app store.I used a similar method to [block the auto apple updates](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-stop-ios-nagging-you-update-latest-version-3641478/#rcjsload_8e5a2b) but I don't know the server responsible for downloading apps.Does anyone know the Domain address?

Comment: Maybe there's a simpler way that I'm not aware of... I'm pretty sure [Little Snitch 4](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) trial can tell you the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out the domain name to block in order to stop installing apps from the app store using tcpdump. The domain name is “aaplimg.com”.Use this address to configure your OpenDNS account.

I tried this method and it is working great.